# Mean js + Mongodb getting empty array

Tags: mongodb, meanjs

I want to read data from mongo using meanjs(CRUD). I have done all necessary mapping and installations but still when I check json data from browser(http://localhost:3000/customerQuotes) I am getting empty array.

```
This is Model.js file

'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var CustomerquotesSchema = new Schema({

    go: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required:'Link label is required'
    },
    show: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''

    },
    thou: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
    }

});

mongoose.model('Customerquotes', CustomerquotesSchema);
```

This is controller.js file

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller'),
    Customerquotes = mongoose.model('Customerquotes'),
    _ = require('lodash');

exports.create = function(req, res) {

    var quoteslink = new Customerquotes(req.body);

    quoteslink.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(quoteslink); 
        }
    });
};
exports.read = function(req, res) {
        //res.json(req.quoteslink);
};

exports.update = function(req, res) {
};
exports.delete = function(req, res) {
};
exports.list = function(req, res) {
        Customerquotes.find().exec(function(err, customerQuotes) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(customerQuotes);
        }
    });
};
```

This is route.js file

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {

var customerQuotes =              require('../../app/controllers/customerquotes.server.controller');

    app.route('/customerQuotes')
        .get(customerQuotes.list)
        .post(customerQuotes.create);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by giving naming convention all in small(and not camelcase) when creating model.js,controller.js and route,js in express(/app folder). Strange to find that this could be the solution but it worked for me :)